# Mobile feed misses events in which a question is edited

Tags: bug, edits, android-app

I noticed that I had a notification for a while today, so I popped open the application to see if it came across in the feed.

It didn't.

Here's the view from my desktop. (Action at top was conveniently placed in green.)

[image]

Here's the view from the app.

[image]

The action to edit the post came within the gap of time that those two new hot questions were posted - about five minutes.

Does this tie into the app not being able to edit/do review queues yet?  It still bugs me that I can't take action on actionable notifications in the app.

Comment: "It still bugs me that I can't take action on actionable notifications in the app." -- Well then it's a good thing that edit suggestion notifications aren't in the feed yet, because you couldn't act on them in the app either :)

Comment: Related: [Edits of your posts not listed in notifications inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/edits-of-your-posts-not-listed-in-notifications-inbox)